# Solve $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{ky^3 +ey}{axy(y+b) + c(y-b)/\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on a physics project and have to solve this nonlinear ODE:-

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{ky^3 +ey}{axy(y+b) + c(y-b)/\sqrt{x}},$$

where $a, b, c, k$ and $e$ are constants.

I haven't had much experience solving nonlinear ODEs, but I did try obtaining a Taylor series solution. It turned out to be far too complicated though. I do know there are simpler numerical methods, but I'm looking for an analytical solution. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you really need to solve it or qualitative behaviour is fine too?

Comment: Are you sure that an analytical solution exists?  Unfortunately many nonlinear ODEs can not be solved analytically.

Comment: @Doubt: I'm not familiar with uniqueness and existence theorems yet, so I can't say for sure. And I'm not aware of any other techniques that would tell me that, either.

Comment: @Evgeny: I do need to solve it, as the function obtained has to be used elsewhere. Behavior of the solution won't suffice. However, if such a solution does not exist, that would be valuable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple case where $a, b,c,k ,e = 1$, Mathematica gives the solution implicitly as
\begin{align}
\int_1^{y(x)}\frac{\xi-2}{\xi\left(1+\xi^2\right)^{7/4}\exp\left(\frac{3}{2}\arctan\xi\right)}\,d\xi = \frac{2x^{3/2}}{3\left(1+y^2(x)\right)^{3/4}\exp\left(\frac{3}{2}\arctan y(x)\right)} + c
\end{align}
There does not seem to be a closed-form expression for the integral, unfortunately.  Probably this form is no more helpful than the original ODE in terms of solving the problem numerically.

Comment: Thank you for trying! I guess this is the closest one could get to a solution. But just out of curiosity (and desperateness), if I had an initial condition like $y(0)=0$, would that help in any way?

Comment: No, the initial condition is not likely to make things easier.  In fact, the initial condition $y(0) = 0$ may not be physically possible since $dy/dx|_{x=0,\,y=0}$ is undefined.  Easier would be $y(0) = 1$, which gives $c = 0$.  If $y(0) = 0$ should be physically possible, perhaps revisit the derivation of the ODE.

Comment: On further reflection, I realized that neither $y(0)=1$, nor $y(0)=0$ are physically possible. The initial conditions are way more complicated than that. Thank you so much for all the help you've done though. I am accepting your answer, as that's the closest in terms of a solution. :)